# Dynamically setting variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to dynamically set variables depending how many vimeo iframes are on my page. Im using the Eval method in my code below:

```
var numberVimeoFrames = jQuery(".vimeo").length;

for(i=1;i<=numberVimeoFrames;i++){
    var refFrame = jQuery('.vimeo:nth-child(' + i + ')');
    eval("player" + i + "= new Vimeo.Player(" + refFrame + ")");
}
```

My eval line is however generating an error message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

To me it looks like ive concatenated correctly so not sure where ive gone wrong?

Comment: `refFrame` is a jQuery object, not a string, it doesn't make sense to concatenate it.

Comment: Any time you think you need dynamic variables, you're probably wrong. You should be using an array or object. When the variables have numeric suffixes like this, it should be an array.

Comment: How could it be done with an array?

Comment: `player[i] = new Vimeo.Player(refFrame);`

Comment: < instead of <=

Comment: Did you consider `var players = jQuery(".vimeo")` and then `players[i]`?

Answer (score 1):

Even though in this case I do not think it is that bad, the general opinion is to not use **eval** at all.
Use arrays instead :

```
var numberVimeoFrames = jQuery(".vimeo").length;

var players = [];
for(i=1;i<=numberVimeoFrames;i++){
    var refFrame = jQuery('.vimeo:nth-child(' + i + ')');
    players.push(new Vimeo.Player(refFrame));
}
```

You can now access your players by calling the array (for example *players[1]* instead of *player1* and so on.)